# Problema con texto de directiva @error en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Estoy con un tutorial CRUD de Laravel, estoy haciendo una validación sencilla:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|min:3'
]);
```

Entonces al aplicar la directiva de **@error** en la plantilla blade:

```
@error('title')
    <h6 class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ $message }}
    </h6>
@enderror
```

Al no cumplirse la validación, me muestra la etiqueta h6 correctamente, pero me muestra el texto "validation.required" en lugar de "The title field is required." (Cosa que se puede personalizar, pero quiero primero entender cómo funciona Laravel)

Siendo que la etiqueta de ese campo es:

```
<input type="text" id="title" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="title"/>
```

Estoy apenas aprendiendo Laravel, pero se supone que el :attribute es el valor del name del campo, también cambie el lenguaje del proyecto así como el time/zone... ¿Alguien puede explicarme?

PHP: 7.4.33
Laravel: 8.83.27

Les dejo una captura de pantalla de referencia, para que tengan contexto:
[image: Formulario CRUD]

Answer (score 0):

Estuve investigando, la verdad soy nuevo con Laravel, el problema fue que que modifique la configuración de la aplicación Laravel (Tu app que desarrollas) en el archivo "app.php", dejo la ruta:

```
config/app.php
```

Lo que configuré fue "Application Locale Configuration", "Application Fallback Locale" y "Faker Locale", los cuales son importantes, lo cual afecta la configuración de idioma de la aplicación Laravel, dejo la explicación de cada punto antes mencionado entre comillas:

1. **Application Locale Configuration (locale)**: *Define el idioma nativo
   de tu aplicación Laravel. En tu caso, lo configuraste como español
   ('es'). Esto implica que Laravel buscará las traducciones y los
   mensajes en español en primer lugar.*
2. **Application Fallback Locale (fallback_locale)**: *Es el idioma al que
   Laravel recurrirá si no puede encontrar una traducción específica en
   el idioma configurado en locale. Mantenerlo en inglés ('en') es una
   buena práctica, ya que el inglés suele tener una cobertura más
   amplia de traducciones en la comunidad Laravel.*
3. **Faker Locale (faker_locale)**: *Define en qué idioma se generarán los
   datos ficticios mediante Faker. Al configurarlo como español ('es'),
   los datos ficticios generados estarán en español, lo que puede ser
   útil si necesitas datos ficticios coherentes con el idioma de tu
   aplicación.*

En mi caso, todos los coloque en "ES", al menos el punto 2 debe quedar en "EN" por buenas prácticas, por el hecho que el idioma inglés es universal, si se puede quedar el punto 1 en "ES" pero debes cambiar a español todo lo correspondiente en app.php